# When using Attention Augmented Convolution Layer from source code in ResUNet , getting error

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, attention-model

I am using AttentiveConv layer from this github: https://github.com/initiativealmendra/DL-architectures/blob/master/AA-CNN.py

Please provide workable solution, I am using
**Operating environment:**

- python version [3.7]
- torch version [1.0.1]
- torch vision [0.2.2]

when I was using this layer in Resunet in PyTorch, I am getting following error:

> RuntimeError: Output 0 of ReshapeAliasBackward0 is a view and is being modified inplace. This view is the output of a function that returns multiple views. Such functions do not allow the output views to be modified inplace. You should replace the inplace operation by an out-of-place one.

Answer (score 0):

Inplace modification of tensor in Pytorch forward function  will made some problems for backward pass.
In your provided link has this problem at line 84 (compute_flat_qkv function)

```
q *= dkh**-0.5
```

You should just change mentioned code to:

```
tmp_tensor =  dkh ** -0.5
q = q* tmp_tensor
```

I have test it and works fine.

This links from Pytorch website could helps you to understand inplace modification basics.

1 - [What is `in-place operation`?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-in-place-operation/16244)

2 - [How to allow in-place modification of saved tensors from forward pass in backward pass?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-allow-in-place-modification-of-saved-tensors-from-forward-pass-in-backward-pass/137922)

Comment: Yes. It is run for the source code @Masoud_Amj.

Comment: but when I am using this AttentiveCon layer from soucecode in Standard ResUNet in PyTorch for input_shape = (3,256,256), the following error is getting:

'code'
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 9.38 GiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 1004.70 MiB already allocated; 8.87 GiB free; 4.63 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Comment: Please respond me. It will get more help for me.

Comment: @ParmeshwarPatil This error is for GPU memory. this model is too large for fit in 16GB GPU.
You can load it on the CPU for do tests. NOTE: it's need large RAM and if you doesn't have You can increase you Page File size